# Invalid write of size 4 when malloc

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

my program is like this:

```
char *line = "hello a b c d e f g ";
/* split it into words */
char **argv = NULL;
**argv = malloc(sizeof(char*));
if (*argv = NULL)
    printf("null malloc");
    printf("malloc ok");
    int i;
    for (i=0;;i++){
        printf("i=%d", i);
        line = strwrd(line, argv[i], 1024, " \t");
        printf("strwrk ok");
        if (argv[i] = NULL)
             break;
        **argv = realloc(*argv, (i+2)*sizeof(char*));   
        printf("realloc ok");
    }
}
```

when I run it in valgrind, it says that:

```
==22169== Invalid read of size 4
==22169==    at 0x804858B: main (printTest.c:27)
==22169==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

cuz I'm a rookie in C, so I don't know if malloc has some thing wrong.

Comment: You *are* assigning the result of `malloc`ing space for a `char *` to a `char`, not to mention dereferencing a null pointer as you do.

Comment: `if (*argv = NULL)` is an assignment, you should be comparing for equality: `if (*argv == NULL)`. I originally posted this as an answer but there are like at least 5 other things wrong here so I give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**argv = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

should be

```
argv = malloc(sizeof(*argv));
```

Comment: NB: please read some more tutorials and/or re-read them more carefully. This is just too basic.